# Android - SugarORM - select object from table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sugarorm

I create table in SQLite Database thanks to SugarORM in Android.

```
public class ProjectPhotoData extends SugarRecord<ProjectPhotoData> {


public boolean isSent;
public int pictureType;

public ProjectPhotoData() {

}


public ProjectPhotoData( boolean isSent, int pictureType) {


    this.isSent = isSent;
    this.pictureType = pictureType;

}
```

But I don't know how to retrieve object from this table?

For example I save objects in this table:

```
    ProjectPhotoData photoData = new ProjectPhotoData(false,5);
    photoData.save();
    ProjectPhotoData photoDataSecond = new ProjectPhotoData(true,3);
    photoDataSecond.save();
```

And how to retrive object where pictureType is 5?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the query builders to query the data. There are some examples here http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html

```
ProjectPhotoData.find(ProjectPhotoData.class, "picture_type = ?", "5");
```

Comment: How would I find picture_type == 5 or picture_type == 3